# How can i relock bootloader of infinix smart 2 with or without data loss?

Tags: bootloader

How can i relock bootloader of infinix smart 2 with or without data loss? i haven't install twrp and root device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you have not made any modifications to the device, then the usual oem lock command should be all that you need to do:

```
fastboot oem lock-go
```

After that confirm the lock on the phone and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should not lose any Data `Re-locking` the bootloader of an uncompromised system. It is only when the bootloader is Un-locked does the data loss occurr. A little insight into bootloaders is that it is an actual security function of the bootloaders to eject the possible compromised files if checks fail.

The bootloader will verify that everything is good to go if not then the bootloader has the option to essentially factory reset your device by Un-locking to dispose of what it believes to be non-native binaries or files. The  bootloader Re-locks and starts to verify and attempt to boot again.